# Can you use React-hooks and redux at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, redux

there will be no conflict if using react-cookie and redux,If it react-hooks and redux works, Can a little example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem as though this is possible the react hooks maps the state which is dispatched from a redux store.

You can check..
https://github.com/facebookincubator/redux-react-hook

There is a good how to article here 
https://medium.com/maxime-heckel/rebuilding-redux-with-hooks-and-context-e16b59faf51c

hope this helps